# PM2 is not working with esm via docker

Tags: node.js, pm2

Hi my pm2 script in dockerfile(is not working also in my machine)

```
FROM node:8.11.3
RUN npm install -g pm2
RUN npm install -g esm

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

CMD mkdir -p /logs/ && pm2 start app.js --no-daemon --no-autorestart --node-args="-r esm"
```

2 issues: 
sometimes I got errors regarding esm like

```
syntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

and somtimes the app is online and than crash but always never running

my app.js:
import { getServer } from 'node_modules_folder'

var {app, container} = getServer();

```
app.listen(3000, async () => {
    //get logger by container ....

    //print
    logger.info(' web-queue-server Server is up!')
})
```

and the logs is not being fired with pm2

npm start working as it should

Answer (score 2):

`pm2 start app.js` runs in the background. To work with Docker, you have to use `pm2-runtime` command which makes the application run in the foreground.

Do note that some or all of the arguments you are passing to `pm2` may not work with `pm2-runtime`

Refer to the documentation here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/